# Proof Verification/Error: $(x)$ is maximal in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm trying to show that $(x)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$. I *claim* that $(x)$ is in fact a maximal ideal which, as it turns out, isn't the case. What's wrong with the following proof:

First note that,

\begin{align}
(x) = \{ x p(x,y)  \;| \; p(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y] \}
\end{align}

It is clear that $(x)$ contains exactly those polynomials whose constant term is zero. Define the map,

\begin{align}
\phi: \; & \mathbb{Q}[x,y] \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q} \\
& p(x,y) \longrightarrow a_0,
\end{align}

where $a_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ is the constant term in the polynomial $p(x, y)$. Since $\phi$ is just an evaluation map, we know that it is a homomorphism. By construction, the kernel of $\phi$, is the set of all polynomials whose constant term is zero; so,

\begin{align}
 \ker \phi = (x) \\
\end{align}

which implies that,

\begin{align}
\Longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x) \simeq \mathbb{Q}
\end{align}

as the map is clearly surjective. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x)$ is a field; so, $(x)$ must be a maximal ideal.

Comment: Most errors in proofs are introduced with "Its is clear that ...", note that $y\notin (x)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh, right. I assume, then, the proof will go through for the case of polynomials in one variable, or if I replace the ideal with the ideal $(x, y)$.

Comment: @JunaidAftab That is correct. Although you can use a similar argument to show that $(x)$ is prime in this case. Can you find a surjection $\mathbb{Q}[x,y] \to \mathbb{Q}[y]$?

Comment: @leibnewtz I was able to show that $(x)$ by simply applying the definition. Finding a surjection shouldn't be too hard now, though.